# React Native how to pass google play store and App Store url parameters to input

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsx

How to pass google play store and app store url parameters value to input field?

for example, `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={appID}&hl=en&referrer=ABC123`

i want to pass the `ABC123` to referrer input field after the user installed the app.

i have tried, `Linking` but the `Linking` will only work when the user app is installed.

What i trying to do is,

1. When the user not installed the app.
2. go to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={appID}&hl=en&referrer=ABC123`
3. App installed
4. When opened the app auto field up referrer field to `ABC123`

Answer (score 4):

**Sep 2023 Update:** Firebase is shutting down Dynamic Links on Aug 2025. They advised to use other alternatives like AppsFlyer etc
https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq.

You can make use of [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/). If a user clicks your link, and doesn't have the app installed, user would be redirected to the app store to download. After download, the app launches and you can then process the link.

1. Set up Firebase Dynamic Links (by following the docs above)
2. Set up [Deep Linking in React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) to handle deep links in your app
3. Add data you intend to pass (in your case, referral link etc) to the dynamic link
4. User clicks on your link and is redirected to app store or play store to download the app.
5. After download, user launches app
6. Then the Linking module you set up in step 2 will handle the deep link and extract the data you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).